# How to recompile PHP

Tags: linux, php, ssh

I have changed some settings in various things on my site and I am being told i need to "recompile PHP" via ssh.

can anybody tell me how to do that?

OOF, harsh - people wanna shut this one real fast.

Heres the situation. I have some nice preg_matches going on throughout my site, but the server I am on is throwing up errors left and right, complaining about my PCRE not being UTF-8 friendly.

After researching the problem, it seems the only way to make it friendly is by recompiling PHP with a few flags in the conditions.

And that is where I'm at.

Comment: Recompiling PHP is almost always a last resort. You need to talk more in detail about your situation in order to get at what you really need.

Comment: What OS?  If it's a Linux distro, it's often easiest to start with the source package and modify it to add whatever extra options you need.

Comment: okay...so basically a fresh install?

Comment: Since you're modifying the source package for PHP, the result will be a new PHP package which you can use to install "over" your existing installation.  This only works if PHP was originally installed via package, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by figuring out how to connect to your server via ssh. Then use wget to download the latest php sources. cd into the directory with the unzipped files. Run configure with the options you want, then run make.

Here is the official FAQ: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.build.php

Comment: Hmmm... better edit my post. The site is down.

Comment: There. A new working link!

Comment: thanks george:) sorry on the delay for checkin you as answer

Answer (score 0):

We have many roads that lead to Rome. If you want to recompile PHP, then you should first check your server. Which OS are you using? Which PHP version? Are there any Bundled PHP Extension you want to use?... and so on.

Recompiling PHP in general is like this:

- searching for the official PHP source code
- invoking `./configure`. For example like this: `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql`
  See a full list of configure options: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php
- invoking `make`
- invoking `make install`

Please have a look at these tutorials:

Official tutorial (PHP is installed as an Apache2 module):
https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php (See step 5.)

You could also check at the offical github page. 
https://github.com/php/php-src

Unofficial tutorial: 
http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-recompile-php-with-gd-support-on-a-live-serv-1572.html